# Better than Hadamard Codes?

Tags: coding-theory, hadamard-matrices

Hadamard codes are known to be optiml for k ≤ 7 in the sense of minimum distance (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_code#Optimality). For k > 7 cases, does there exist any better codes than Hadamard codes? I think this may comes to two ends: 1) fewer codewords with same minimum distance, or 2) equal codewords with larger minimum distance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Depends on the optimality criterion. There are several bounds like Hamming bound and Singleton bound.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.